# Why do people in movies commit suicide by slitting their wrists in the wrong direction?

Tags: realism

It is commonly known that the probability of surviving after slitting your wrists is much higher if you cut horizontally and that you should cut along the forearm to cut a longer portion of the artery and bleed quicker if you plan to commit suicide.

However, people are often depicted in movies slitting their wrists horizontally.

Is this done on purpose to increase the probability that somebody imitating the movie will survive for example, or is this just a mistake or a coincidence that a majority of movies follow this convention?

Comment: Your question sounds more answerable from the perspective of "Is this to prevent successful suicide imitation?" than from the general way that it's ended now ("or is this just a mistake or coincidence?").

Comment: Doing research for this question I discovered that committing suicide by cutting one's self in any manner is very low, statistically, and by cutting one's wrist is even lower, and that there is no (that I could find after two hours of research) statistics for or against the efficacy of horizontal vs vertical cutting of one's wrist. As a layman, I would probably prefer, (were I contemplating suicide) to use the cross wrist cut, so as to ensure the whole vein is cut. I am more positive, however, that if I were contemplating suicide, for real, the exacting method would not be a high worry for me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about movies/tv shows. For a question of this nature to be answered in an objective way, one would need be a medical professional, not a movie buff, therefor it is off topic, in my opinion.

Comment: I agree that it would not add value to a movie community. But as a former paramedic and med student for 3 years, I assure you there ARE effective ways to do it. Although I am loath to discuss them as it seems unhelpful to the community to know how to do it right. Needless to say the reason they are ineffective in a large number of cases is the fact that most hesitate and frankly don't want to die. More of a cry for attention.

Comment: I go with Luis answer., if i plan to commit suicide i do same mistake because till now I don't know these information.. Even directors aware of these, they have to think in the way the character does.,

Comment: This isn't off topic; its about a **cinematic convention** of depicting suicide in an inefficient way: whether there was some kind of consensus on showing it this way. With a little research, this could produce a *fantastic* answer...

Comment: I'm with @JohnSmithOptional here, this can be an interesting look into something that is commonly depicted in films, as well as opens up a whole avenue of question types dealing with typical movie tropes/conventions Wording needs a bit of cleanup, however

Comment: Thanks for the comments; I'm sorry for the wording of the question, but I'm not english, so it wasn't very clear. I thougth this question to be on topic here because there could be historical reasons (ie: a movie depicted suicide this way and everybody else copied it) or practical ones as I hinted in the question, either way it seems to be a convention for movies and there could be an interesting reason behind it

Comment: @Alessandro, I think your question was worded fine mate (it made sense at least), I think people are just sometimes very quick to shoot people down here... you're right, this is interesting. I wonder where this trend came from, as so many people have pointed out it's inefficiency... I may attempt this myself, if I find a spare afternoon: hopefully someone here will get there before me and save me the effort! Interesting question, anyway...+1

Comment: @CGCampbell cutting across the vein can easily be stopped by pressure or clotting and the vein can be repaired in surgery. Cutting down the vein results in severe blood loss, and had someone stopped the bleeding in time, makes it almost impossible to repair easily.

Comment: Since it's always shown in the movies that way, and, no, most people aren't versed in the actual best/most fatal wrist cutting literature, maybe the characters in the movies cut their wrists that way because they always see it done that way in the movies.

Comment: In Drive, Bryan Cranston's character is killed by having his wrist slit the "correct" way. Not actually suicide, but done right at least.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Movies are for telling stories and entertaining. To do that effectively, it is sometimes easier to repeat an incorrect but widely held belief. Showing a more factual version may be more difficult, may take more screen time, or may break up the flow of the story.

For example, many ways that firearms are depicted in movies are factually wrong (or impractical or both) but have become familiar enough that they can be repeated and everyone watching understands what is supposed to be happening. Likewise, movies regularly show elevators failing and falling down. When elevators fail, they fall up (I have experience with it. I know. Also a recent news story shows a [video](http://news.yahoo.com/blogs/odd-news/man-gets-trapped-in-out-of-control-elevator-that-rockets-up-to-the-roof-before-stopping--with-video--191943106.html) of it happening). It would take to much screen time to explain this to viewers, and that gets in the way of the *story* (unless the story *is* about elevators or guns and how they work).

Also, I am sure that no one wants to make the movie that helps anyone commit suicide. If they're determined, they'll find out on their own, but I don't want to help them.

Comment: Surprised no one mentioned The Big Chill yet, which is the exception to the rule: as can be seen in [the opening credit sequence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0KbKONipqg) (around 3:14), the deceased Alex has slashed his wrists *vertically*.

Comment: The elevator issue highly depends on what fails. If the cable on the counter weight fails, both the cab and the weight fall down. Even when the brakes fail and the counter weight falls, the cab does fall "up", but then the counter weight hits the floor and shatters, so the cab also falls down.

Comment: @cde If you've seen that happen, then I can only accept that you're right. I've seen the opposite. The car stayed at the top of the shaft until it was manually lowered by repairmen.

Answer (score -2):

Statistics show that most people who try to commit suicide don't really want to die.  That should be enough for their being unsuccessful in the attempt.  In addition, even those who really want to die don't have any knowledge of anatomy so as to perforate the right artery. Movie makers aren't any experts either.